# how to show JSON Data in HTMl Page

Tags: json, html

I have HTML web page i want to show the data which is in JSON Format in HTML web page so that it should Group Names from JSON Data only in HTML Web Page.

here is the data URL

```
 http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getGroups.php?organizationCode=att&userId1
```

I have search on net it gets the local JSON data but how to access data using URL as mine data here is the JSFiddle of local which I got

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"common_search":{"strBusinessName":"Sun Shine Vision","strAddress":"Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn","intPhone":""}, "cache_table":{"Details":"Speedtrax,Ample\'s Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"}}');

$("#common_serachdiv").html(obj.common_search.strBusinessName);
$("#cache_table").html(obj.cache_table.Details);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nFUVs/

Answer (score 0):

You would want to call an url using jquery ajax

E.g.

```
var url = 'http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getGroups.php?organizationCode=att&userId1';

$("#common_serachdiv").html(url);
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
}.done(function( data ) {
    $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $("#common_serachdiv").html(item.GroupTitle);
    }
}
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: based upon the real data from the url provided I have updated my question.  I do not think it is possible to do this in jsfiddle, and if you are accessing an external site please consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy